# Change in behavior for controller parameter binding in NET7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I have an object as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract()]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to post a list of objects to an API by doing:

```
public async void SaveAsync(IEnumerable<MyObject> items, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(mySaveUrl, items, ct);
}
```

And the API endpoint is:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<DTO.MyObject>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[HttpPost("SaveObjects")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveObjects(IEnumerable<DTO.MyObject> items)
{
    await myService.SaveAsync(items);
    return Ok();
}
```

However, when the endpoint is reached, the value of the `items` parameter is an empty array.

This was tried and tested code and was working for years and through many iterations of .NET.

To get the list to serialize successfully I now do need to add `[FromBody]`. I'm testing this directly with my WebAPI project.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Is this a breaking change in NET7 as nowhere in my solution where I post lists of objects is working anymore. Which properties of the `ApiBehaviorOptions` class need to be set to get the same behavior as in NET6?

Here the [list of breaking changes in NET7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/7.0).

Comment: Try to use `List` instead of `IEnumerable` in `SaveObjects` parameters and in `ProducesResponseType`

Comment: On a side note, I highly doubt you need the attributes on your DTO at all. Is this .net framework by any chance?

Comment: Try adding attribute `[FromBody]` in the parameter and pass list of items as a body while hitting the endpoint

Comment: This should  work as is, I tried it myself and items collection is bound (not empty) are you sure you're sending items json in body? What are you testing with? Postman, Swagger...?

Comment: While you are binding the `items` array does it followed the `DataMember` order? In addition, could please share how are you getting the `items` request? from `postman` or view?

Comment: @Nino Is the parameter type `List` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono `IEnumerable`, just like in your code.

Comment: @Nino Are you using NET6 or NET7? If you upgrade to NET7 will it work or not?

Comment: @NET6. NET 6 is LTS (long time support) version, so it will be supported for three years. I woundn't recommend hurrying with 7.0

Comment: Did you have [`[ApiController]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apicontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) applied?  And if so, to the controller itself, or to the assembly?